Best way to save information as it was in database
Database is MariaDB.
So let's say I have two tables demand and installation (we keep this simple but in reality I have multiple tables to deal with).
table demand: uuid, reference, statut, json_col, createdat, energy and ref_uuid_installation,
table installation: uuid, address, zip_code, type_installation and sector
Both of them are joint with primary/foreign key like this: installation.uuid = demand.ref_uuid_installation.
Now here's the problem: The informations of an installation can be updated at any moment BUT when we query the demand table we MUST retrieve the installation informations as it was when it was asked.
Right now the demand table has a JSON column that saves the installation informations so even if the installation later is updated the old informations is stored in the json col. Heres how we query the demand table :
SELECT *
FROM demand d
WHERE d.json_col LIKE '%"installation name" : "jolio"'
AND  d.json_col LIKE '%"installation code" : "5547ED4"'
OR d.json_col LIKE '%"installation code" : "7869F11"'
AND  d.json_col LIKE '%"installation zip_code" : "11475"'
...etc 

The problem is that the demand table has several millions rows in it so when we try to query all the demand that was related to an installation back then it takes ages to give us a result.
What is the best way (architectural wise) to store this kind of data and have quick load when we query it can be anything:  tables structure, use file to store.. I'm open to anything.

Please [edit] your question to include the table structures you have, example data you have, what the possible changes in the installation tables are and example data for these changes.

What do you mean by "when it was asked"?  If you're talking about simultaneous updates, then there is no such thing, right?  Two queries one second apart might get different results, as they should.  You'll get the information as it exists when you do the query.

"when we query the demand table we MUST retrieve the installation informations as it was when it was asked" - do you mean you want to retrieve the historical result for a SELECT i.e. even if the resultset were to change, you want the old one? It sounds like you need to cache a resultset, which you could do in another table.

@halfer yes exactly. So when i do a select to get the demand i need the installation as it was when he respond to the demand.
So as i said in the post, a column json was created to store the installation informations. So even if the installation later is updated so old information could be retrieve. The problem is sometimes i need to SELECT a demand based on the old information of the installation and when you have 5 millions rows of demand it takes way too long to have the result. I want to optimize this.

@halfer So Right now to query the demand table it's like : SELECT * from demand where json_col like [...] AND json_col like [...] AND json_col like [...] AND json_col like [...]... etc

Could you build a table cache, which issues the big query if a cache row does not exist, and then stores the result in the cache? Then if the query is issued again, the cache record can be detected, which (1) gets you the historical data you want, and (2) is faster than the original query.

In relation to querying JSON columns, does MariaDB not have JSON operators like Postgres? Using LIKE forces the use of full table scans, which feels awfully inefficient.

Yes i already thought of a cache system to store big result from queries (it was my first solution). I would like tho to make a new tables structure without any json store (because its slow to query that column)
What i'm asking in this post is : Is there any better structure solution (knowing the context) to store old data installation with its demand and retrieve them the fastest possible. I suggested to the person a redesign of the DB and he agreed. I already have some options but I'm asking just in case i'm missing better solutions.
Cordially

Either use JSON functions to extract the values or don't use JSON columns.
